# how to collapse with ngx-bootstrap angular without a flag

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

i am trying to do a collapse animation, but without the boolean indicator `isCollapsed`, because i have a lot of elements and i don´t want to make a lot of booleans, there is a way to do that without a boolean indicator?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
        [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseBasic">Toggle collapse
</button>
<hr>
<div id="collapseBasic" [collapse]="isCollapsed">
  <div class="well well-lg card card-block card-header">Some content</div>
</div>
```

component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'collapse-demo',
  templateUrl: './basic.html'
})
export class CollapseDemoComponent {
  isCollapsed = false;
}
```

Thank you!

This example is from the doc `https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/collapse#examples`

Comment: If you have lot of elements, then you will have lots of components. You don't need to have lots of variables indeed.

Comment: @huanfeng then do you have an idea of what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have lots of collapse components.

```
<collapse-demo-animation content="content a"></collapse-demo-animation>
<collapse-demo-animation content="content b"></collapse-demo-animation>
<collapse-demo-animation content="content c"></collapse-demo-animation>
<collapse-demo-animation content="content d"></collapse-demo-animation>
<collapse-demo-animation content="content e"></collapse-demo-animation>
<collapse-demo-animation content="content f"></collapse-demo-animation>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ryym9l-uvya9e

Comment: Yes that could work, but what can i do if i want to send data from the main component to all the components which have the collapse animation? I a mean, each collapse must have their own data to show in it the collapse..

Comment: Please see the updated stackblitz.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ryym9l-uvya9e

Comment: Thanks a lot! your answer was very detailed and descriptive, it helped me to solve my problem, thank you ;)