# All Mat-select values change when i change a single mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have days(in a mat-checkbox) and time ranges (in a mat-select) component. I am able to fetch all the checked values in days. But when i try to change the hours/minutes range in (For eg., Monday), all the days time ranges are changed. Can you please help me in fetching the time ranges for every single day. Like Sunday 9:00 AM to 5:00 PM, Monday 10: 00 AM to 3: 30PM.

The stackblitz url is [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-expansion-panel-c5krm1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a subcomponent to handle each line, creating interfaces to type your code would make it easier to understand also.

The model for each line would look like this :

```js
export interface Slot {
  id: string;
  isChecked: boolean;
  label: string;
  fromHoursSelected: string;
  fromMinutesSelected: string;
  fromAmpmSelected: string;
  toHoursSelected: string;
  toMinutesSelected: string;
  toAmpmSelected: string;
}
```

And you could create a component that can edit this model implementing `ControlValueAccessor` :

```js
export class SlotComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  hoursList: string[] = ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11'];
  minutesList: string[] = ['00', '30'];
  ampmList: string[] = ['AM', 'PM'];

  onChange = (slot) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  model: Slot = {} as Slot;

  writeValue(value: Slot) {
    this.model = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (rating: number) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

}
```

[Here is a running example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-63335805)

Comment: This is what exactly I wanted !! - Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

This is because you used same variable for all hours and all minutes:

`fromHoursSelected` and `fromMinutesSelected`...

Your should have different value for each item:

like:

```
fromMinutesSelected[0] fromMinutesSelected[1] ...
```

The better solution should be you write a component for each row.

Please check my answer in this thread:
[how to collapse with ngx-bootstrap angular without a flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036186/how-to-collapse-with-ngx-bootstrap-angular-without-a-flag/63056477#63056477)